# Unable to both start and discover a specific service with Wifi Direct

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I'm pretty new with Android programming. But I have been working on this for over a week now, and it starts to get booooring.

My idea is that I want to connect two devices using Wifi Direct. But I only want to connect to those which are running my application. Besides, I want the users to be able to see some information of the other devices (such as user name), not just the MAC or the Android_XXXX name included in the WifiP2pDevice. That's why I decided that a device looking for other devices, should both start the application service and search for peers which are also broadcasting this service.

The problem (I'm testing with two real devices) is that, even though they are running exactly the same code, only one of them is getting the service discovery callbacks (the onDnsSd... listeners below). So, one side acts in the proper way, but not the other. Moreover I'm getting "old" services, meaning that apparently each time I start de service (even though I cancel previously started services), that service seems to be still broadcast during at least some minutes.

I include a shortened version of my code:

```
public class MoveFlufietsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements ChannelListener, DeviceActionListener {

    public final HashMap<String, FlufietsPeer> mBuddies = new HashMap<String, FlufietsPeer>();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(getActivity(), getActivity().getMainLooper(), null);
        ...
        startRegistration();
        discoverFlufietsService();
        ...
    }


    public void discoverFlufietsService() {
        DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(String fullDomain, Map record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
                // This and the next listener are only called in one of the devices.
                String serviceName = (String) record.get("serviceName");
                if ((serviceName != null) && (serviceName.equals("flufiets")) {
                    // I put the record data in the mBuddies HashMap.
                    ...
                    mBuddies.put(device.deviceAddress, myPeerDataStructure);
                }
            }
        };

        DnsSdServiceResponseListener servListener = new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice resourceType) {
                if (mBuddies.containsKey(resourceType.deviceAddress)) {
                    FlufietsPeer flufietsPeer = mBuddies.get(resourceType.deviceAddress);
                    WiFiPeerListAdapter adapter = ((WiFiPeerListAdapter) mFragmentList.getListAdapter());
                    adapter.add(flufietsPeer);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

        mManager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(mChannel, servListener, txtListener);

        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        mManager.addServiceRequest(mChannel, serviceRequest, new ActionListener() {
            // onSuccess/onFailure toasts.
        });

        mManager.discoverServices(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            // onSuccess/onFailure toasts.
        });
    }

    public void startRegistration() {
        mManager.clearLocalServices(mChannel, new ActionListener() {
            // onSuccess/onFailure toasts.
        });

        Map record = new HashMap();
        record.put("serviceName", "flufiets");
        ...

        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo serviceInfo = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(flufietsService, "_tcp", record);

        mManager.addLocalService(mChannel, serviceInfo, new ActionListener() {
            // onSuccess/onFailure toasts.
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mManager.clearLocalServices(mChannel, new ActionListener() {
            // onSuccess/onFailure toasts.
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem doesn't seem to be related with the device itself (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, but always only in one of them). I suspect it has to do with either trying to discover a service that we ourselves are broadcasting, or having the same service being offered by two devices. I have tried changing the names of the service, so each device would offer either a "send" or "receive" service, but it doesn't work. I only get the callbacks called (onDnsSd...) in one of the devices.

And that thing about getting old services, when I always clear them, is weird (I do include a timestamp in the service record data, and I could always discard all but the last, but doesn't seem to be logical).

Any ideas? ANY help would be VERY appreciated, because writing the application is not funny any more (:-)=

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Has anybody tried this before here? Please, I'm still wondering what I might be doing wrong...

Comment: Hi, I can also confirm that Android implementation of WiFi Direct behaves inconsistently from time to time. I also have an app connecting to "itself" and notice that one or both instances can stop detecting the presence of each over. I think this is because of too complicated pseudo-optimizations inside the core (including the cache of `remembered groups`, which seems interfered sporadically). What seems helping is: switch OFF `WiFi optimization` check box in WiFi settings and call `discoverPeers`/`stopPeerDiscovery` massively, e.g. by a timeout appropriate for better user experience (~5sec).

Comment: Did you ever got it working? I am experiencing the same scenario,  very random results and only one part gets callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the clearLocalService call succeeds before adding the local service later.  So put the addLocalService call into the onSuccess callback of the clearLocalServices.

Comment: ,.... maybe you could help me also....
it's similar with wifi  case... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357892/how-to-solve-discovering-other-device-via-wi-fi-android-api?noredirect=1#comment37663295_24357892